# Area of a region bounded by $y=\sqrt{|x|}$ and $5y = x+6$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

Find the area of the region bounded by $y=\sqrt{|x|}$
and $5y = x+6$ by looking at where the curves intersected on a graph I got

$$\int_{-1}^4\Bigg[\frac{x+6}{5} - \sqrt{|x|}\Bigg]\,\, dx + \int_4^9 \Bigg[\frac{-(x+6)}{5} + \sqrt{|x|}\Bigg]\,\,dx$$ however I have no idea how to do an intergal with a  square root like this and im not sure if im supposed to or messed up somewhere along the process to get to here. Im studying for my final so explanation of why and not just the solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE in the future please refer to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly typesetting your question

Comment: ok thanks for fixing it for me :)

Comment: If you don't want to integrate $\sqrt{x}$ let $y=\sqrt{x}$ and integrate w.r.t. $y$.

Comment: I have no issue doing \sqrt{x} the confusion was the absolute value thanks for the tip though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\int_{-1}^4 \sqrt{|x|}\,dx=\int_{-1}^0 \sqrt{-x}\,dx+\int_{0}^4 \sqrt{x}\,dx$

**Note:** $\sqrt{-x}$ exists since $x$ is negative in the domain $\int_{-1}^0$

Comment: so breaking everything down I would integrate \int_{-1}^4 (x+6)/5\,dx-(\int_(-1)^0 \sqrt{-x} + \int_(0)^4 \sqrt{-x}) - \int_(4)^9 -(x+6)/5 + \int_(4)^9 \sqrt {x} if im correct?

Comment: It won't let me edit my comment anymore I was trying to fix the typesetting

Comment: in $\int_0^4$ it is $\sqrt{x}$. Also a minus sign would precede the integral. @AlexChapp. Check the signs again, the second last integrand would also be preceded by a $+$ sign (I think you wanted to take the minus sign out, and forgot to remove it from the integrand?).

Comment: ok I can compute those integrals thanks for the help